# Uikit - afterFilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit

Because of the `uk-scrollspy`, when cliking between WHITE-BLUE-BLACK there is a bug during `300ms`. You can see the différence if you do ALL-BLUE or ALL-BLACK.

So I'd like to `destoy` the `uk-scrollspy attribute` with `$detroy` from `uikit` but didn't managed.

**JS** :

```
$('[uk-filter]').on('afterFilter', function() {
    $('[uk-scrollspy]').component.$destroy(true);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/769f5au4/11/)

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution :

**JS:**

```
var firstFilter = true;

$('[uk-filter]').on('beforeFilter', function() {
    if (!firstFilter) {
        $('[uk-scrollspy]').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-slide-bottom');
            $(this).removeAttr('uk-scrollspy');
            $(this).css('visibility', '');
            UIkit.scrollspy(this).$destroy();
        });
    }

    firstFilter = !firstFilter;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/769f5au4/85/)